# dynamic memory across static libraries

Tags: c++

I have a static library which contains the majority of my code/objects.  I have another library which inherits some of these objects:  E.G.

```
class SomeClass <-- from base library

class AnotherSomeClass : public SomeClass <--another library
```

In SomeClass I have another object SomeObject which is also inherited in same way.

```
SomeObject *newobject = new AnotherSomeObject(); //for example SomeObject exists in one of the base classes in another library.
```

I then upcast to access the function which exist only in the subclass like so:

```
AnotherSomeObject *object = (AnotherSomeObject*)newobject;
```

All is working well, except when I release memory, which is done in the base class.  I got: _ASSERTE(_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse))

This only appeared recently which was hard to diagnose, because it was working fine until I made some changes to some of the classes.

I now delete the the subclass object (which inherits the base class object) and then set the base class object to NULL instead, which seems to be working.

The question is why does this happen?

Comment: Do you have a virtual destructor in the base class ?

Comment: Well, use dynamic_cast<> instead, this is what it is made to do.  Corrupting the heap is otherwise an every day C++ problem.

Comment: Yochai Timmer - I just checked expecting it to be a virtual destructor and noticed that is doesn't.  Most of my other classes which are expecting to be inherited in such a way do.  Could this be the cause?  It will take a while to compile, so will get back to you.

Comment: [expr.delete]/3 "In the first alternative (`delete object`), if the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its
dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and **the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined.**"

Comment: Even if it doesn't use `delete`, the fact that it doesn't have a virtual dtor seems to indicate it isn't made to be derived from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to have a virtual destructor in the base class when inheriting.

When you call delete later on in the program, if you don't have a virtual destructor, the compiler will generate code that calls the destructor that belongs to the type that the current variable happens to be.

So, if you are holding a pointer of the base class type, the base class destructor will be used.
If you are holding a pointer to the derived class type, the derived class destructor will be used.

This may cause all kinds of problems, most frequently you can spot it by seeing very-hard-to-find memory leaks.

Comment: Yes, this appears to have been the problem.  Human error.  When I originally wrote the base class I didn't expect to inherit it, but I later discovered that I needed to inherit it and forgot to add the virtual to the destructor.  Cheers for pointing me in the right direction. :)

Comment: @DyP yeap, that's what i meant.